# User Creation Problem in AAD

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, azure-ad, azure-ad-graph-api

```
newUser.DisplayName = objUser.DisplayName;
            newUser.UserPrincipalName = objUser.UserPrincipalName;
            newUser.AccountEnabled = true;
            newUser.MailNickname = "SampleAppDemoUser";
            newUser.CompanyName = objUser.CompanyName;
            newUser.PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
            {
                Password = objUser.PasswordProfile.Password,
                ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = objUser.PasswordProfile.ForceChangePasswordNextLogin
            };

            newUser.Mobile = objUser.Mobile;
            newUser.Department = objUser.Department;
            newUser.JobTitle = objUser.JobTitle;
            newUser.City = objUser.City;
            newUser.UsageLocation = objUser.UsageLocation;


ActiveDirectoryClient clientUserCreate = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();
clientUserCreate.Users.AddUserAsync(newUser).Wait(10000);
var userid = newUser.ObjectId;
```

I am trying to create AAD user using above code. It is not throwing any error. Code runs smoothly. But it is not creating user in AD. When I am trying to get objectid of newly created user it gives null value.

If you have any idea then please suggest me. Is this issue related to Azure Configuration or permission or related to code ?

Comment: How have you defined your `newUser`? If it's not defined, nothing will be added.

Comment: Please check I have edited my answer now with newuser object setting

Comment: I assume you have also registered the `newUser` variable too. Have you done this as `IUser newUser = new User();`?

Comment: Yes I have done that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating object assigning property then after was the cause of it.

I had replaced code from :

```
Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User objUser = new Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User();

objUser.DisplayName = "Test";

objUser.AccountEnabled  = true;
...
```

to

```
Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User objUser = new Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User

{

DisplayName = "Test";

AccountEnabled  = true;

...

};
```

I have not figure out what is the difference between those two methods but it solves my issue. If you can figure out that difference then please post it.

Comment: Mark this as answer if it helps you.